# How can I clone FileStream type?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, clone

How can I clone FileStream type?

The problem is that I using `MagickNet.Image(inputStream)` to get the image distentions before saving it, but it seems to closing the inputStream.

So, I can send a clone of inputStream to the function, so the function cannot edit the real inputStream object?

This is my function:

```
public Picture GetPictureDimension(Stream inputStream, Picture picture)
{
    var img = new MagickNet.Image(inputStream);

    picture.Width = img.Columns;
    picture.Height = img.Rows;

    return picture;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just re-open the file? But to keep a single `Stream` without it getting closed, you could try `NonClosingStreamWrapper` in [MiscUtil](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/). Just be sure to reset the `Position` if appropriate.

Comment: I don't really sure that MagickNet.Image close the stream, as it is lacking documentation, but I do sure that after this function, the `readStream.Read` return zero bytes. So, I the first thing that I think how to debug this is to creat a clone of the stream type, but after looking how to do that it seems not trivial task. So this ring the question how do we cloning types like this one?

Comment: Read will do that if the stream position is at the end. It most likely just read to the end of the stream.

Comment: If it was a closed stream, Read would throw.

Comment: @Mendy - in that case, are you sure it isn't just at the end of the stream? Try setting `theStream.Position = 0;` before calling `Read(...)`.

Comment: @Josh: you are right. @Marc: Thanks. But can you answer the question, do we can clone this types of objects in c#?

Comment: @Mendy - because the source of the stream is *external* and unmanaged, there is not going to be a managed way to clone it.

Comment: @Marc: Just to make it close. What thinks I can do, to clone this variable in .net. Can I use c++ for this?

Comment: @Mendy - I wouldn't have thought so, no. You would ultimately be doing the same thing as opening the file twice - you'd need two underlying file handles. So either open it twice or rewind it.

Comment: The link to MiscUtil is dead

Comment: @DaveInCaz fixed

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post full code, but I imagine that `MagickNet.Image(inputStream)` gets the full image and you only use the Size from that, and later you load the Image a second time.

So a more practical solution would be to get and hold the Image in memory just once. That gives you access to the Size.

### Edit:

You don't seem to realize it but you are asking how to load the Image twice (w/o reopening the stream). I do think it is more efficient to load it just once.

Picture is a XNA class, right? I don't know to much about that but you could try something like:

```
public Picture GetPictureDimension(Stream inputStream, ref Picture picture)
{
    var img = new MagickNet.Image(inputStream);

    picture = new Picture(img);  // just guessing here
    //picture.Width = img.Columns;
    //picture.Height = img.Rows;

    return picture;
}
```

Comment: I'm hold it only once, but unfortunately `Image(inputStream)` Corrupting it, so I'm asking how to **clone** it, so I don't need to load it twice.

Comment: No, you are loading it (into `img`) and then discard it after using only the size. Wasteful.

Comment: @Mendy: Yes, you are discarding it. `img` is a local var and you loose it. Just hold on to the image and you don't need to clone the Stream.

Comment: @Henk: loosing `img` doesn't mean losing `inputStream` too. `inputStream` remains referenced.

Comment: @mendy: But InputStream becomes 'used up'. As Streams do. And it is always wasteful to read it twice.

Comment: @Henk: can you give me a solution how I can avoid read it twice? here is the case: I have a stream form somewhere (user upload the file). I want to get the picture Dimension, and after that save the file to the file system. are you say that you have a way to do it at once?

Comment: Quote: You have a Stream and you want to 'save the file'. You can load the Picture, take the size and then save the picture.